# Adding a limiter that gives an error if a wrong number is insertd to a textfield in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, awt

I have a code database with a graphical user interface and id like it to give the user a polite error if the user enters a code that is not specified.(outside the area of 0 to 30) how should i do that? Here is my code that i have written so far.

```
public class koodibaasiteinetäiustus extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField tfCount;
public koodibaasiteinetäiustus() {
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setResizable(false); 
    cp.add(new JLabel("enter code"));
    tfCount = new JTextField ("0", 10);
    tfCount.setEditable(true);
    cp.add(tfCount);
    JButton nupp = new JButton("give answer");
    cp.add(nupp);
    cp.add(new JLabel("zero equals text"));
    nupp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String[] array;
            array = new String[31];
            array[0] = "text";
            array[1] = "643201";
            array[2] = "643202";
            array[3] = "643203";
            array[4] = "643204";
            array[5] = "643205";
            array[6] = "643206";
            array[7] = "643207";
            array[8] = "643208";
            array[9] = "643209";
            array[10] = "643210";
            array[11] = "643211";
            array[12] = "643212";
            array[13] = "643213";
            array[14] = "643214";
            array[15] = "643215";
            array[16] = "643216";
            array[17] = "643217";
            array[18] = "643218";
            array[19] = "643219";
            array[20] = "643220";
            array[21] = "643221";
            array[22] = "643222";
            array[23] = "643223";
            array[24] = "643224";
            array[25] = "643224";
            array[26] = "643226";
            array[27] = "643227";
            array[28] = "643228";
            array[29] = "643229";
            array[30] = "643230";

            int number = Integer.parseInt(tfCount.getText());
            tfCount.setText(String.valueOf(array[number]));

        }

    });
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Koodibaas");
    setSize(300, 100);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
             SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    new koodibaasiteinetäiustus();
                 }
             });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the problem, can't you just use an if?

```
if( numeber>=0 && number<=30) {
    ...
} else {
    error
}
```

you can also check the format when you convert it into int, it give exception if the user insert not a number:

```
try { 
    number = Integer.parseInt(tfCount.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> that is not specified.(outside the area of 0 to 30)

Use a `JSpinner` which allows you to specify a number range.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: So far i got this, but the spinner still wont load:JFrame frame = new JFrame("Limiting value for a JSpinner");
    SpinnerModel sm = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 30, 1); 
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(sm);// got it between add label and add button. got rid og the textfield code.